# Populate a networkx graph with tuples of varying lengths

Tags: python, graph

I've got a list with tuples of variable length containing nodes, out of which I want to build a network:

```
node_list = [("one", "two"), ("eins", "zwei", "drei"),
             ("un", "deux", "trois", "quattre"), ("two", "zwei", "deux")]
```

Each tuple represents a subgroup in the network. I want to add each node with edges to any other member of the same tuple.

It is straightforward to use `.add_edges_from()`, which only expects a tuple with two nodes. For a tuple with three entries one would have to write `.add_edges_from(("eins", "zwei"), ("eins", "drei"), ("zwei", "drei"))`. Tuples with four members require even more code.

Now I am looking for the most efficient way to populate a network given a list like `node_list`. My idea is:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
for node_tuple in node_list:
    for node1 in node_tuple:
        for node2 in node_tuple:
            G.add_edge(node1, node2)
```

It's probably very inefficient because it sees every node twice and also adds self-loops.

Comment: Wouldn't this also create edges from each node to itself? Is that intended?

Comment: It is. Simply populating with nodes is easy, but the edges make the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples of varying lengths are a bit unusual.  Perhaps those would be better as lists instead.

[`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is your friend.  You can write, equivalently:

```
import itertools

G = nx.Graph()
for node_tuple in node_list:
    G.add_edges_from(itertools.product(node_tuple, node_tuple))
```

If you want to list each pair of nodes just once instead of twice, and including self-edges use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(node_tuple, 2)` instead.

Comment: `combinations` will omit the self-edges: you need [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

Comment: `combinations_with_replacement()` did the trick. It's also good to know that there is `combinations`, in case one wants self-edges.